# Custom step UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, uislider

I just download Park Guides app (by National Geographic) and I'm wondering what's the best way to implement their UISlider. It works step by step and it's really nice customized.

Ideas ? :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `UISlider` for that.  I'd probably start by using a `UISegmentedControl`.  It has a [bunch of methods for customizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW28) its appearance that you could use to get it all fancy-shmancy looking.

Failing that, I'd build my own control.  `UISlider` *might* work, but it's not really intended to be used for discrete intervals like this.

Comment: You're right I didn't think about this component. thx !

Comment: I think it's an UISegmented control overlayed with an UIScrollView (paging enabled)